# How to make an ItemsControl that has only the special type?

Tags: wpf, panel, itemscontrol

My English skills are poor because I'm not a native English speaker.
I hope that you can understand.

I would like to construct a control that can receive only a special type.
I am thinking of constructing it deriving ItemsControl.
First, I tried to construct it deriving Panel but I thought that the way is unsuitable at this subject so I tried to use the ItemControl.

Anyway, here my problem is the ItemCollection of the ItemsControl can has all types but I want the control I try to construct to have only a special type.

For example, The construction of the code I expect is as follows.
(The name of the control that I'm trying to construct assumed "DockManager".)
(The name of the special type that "DockManager" can have, assumed "DockLayout" and "DocumentLayout".)

A successful example.

```
<DockManager>
    <DockLayout Header="example" Content="{Binding}" DockManager.Dock="Top"/>
    <DockLayout Header="example2" Content="{Binding}" DockManager.Dock="Bottom"/>
    <DocumentLayout Header="example2" Content="{Binding}"/>
</DockManager>
```

Example of failure

```
<DockManager>
    <Grid/>      <-- Error : DockManager can't has the Grid control.
    <TextBox/>   <-- Error : DockManager can't has the TextBox control.
</DockManager>
```

Could I reach the above goal in the base on ItemsControl?
I am not willing to cling to ItemsControl.
If you have a better way that can reach the above goal, could you teach me the way?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: An ItemsControl is typically used to manage data items (i.e. instances of a data item class) which are not UI elements. Yours looks more like a custom Panel.

Comment: Thank you for advice. but if derived from the panel, because the control can have all types, I would try to create a custom control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I reach the above goal in the base on `ItemsControl`?

Short answer: No.

An `ItemsControl` has an `ItemsSource` property that can be set to any `IEnumerable` and you can't change this API by creating a new class that derives from it.

So if you want a control that only works with a spcific type of items, you will have to create your own custom control from scratch basically. You may take a look at the [source code of the `ItemsControl`](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/master/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs) and proceed from that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I would try to create a custom control following your advice.